# Looking for script to get coords from a google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, coordinates

I have been looking for a script which lets you search a map for a location and lets you click the map to put the clicked coordinates into a form. So far I have had no luck!

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using v3 api to click on the map and get the lat/lng of the location:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e){
    alert('lat: ' + e.latLng.lat() + ' lng: ' + e.latLng.lng());
})
```

see example http://jsfiddle.net/6aGf7/